# Python, How to add incremental suffix to the duplicate excel cell values

Tags: python-3.x, openpyxl

I am new to Python.Need help to update an excel cell values. Trying to add incremental suffix with duplicate values or values exists more than one time in excel spread sheet.

Using OpenPyxl, Tried as per below but its not working as expected..actually my objective is to add incremental suffix to the cell values if the cell value exists more than one time.

My sample Code:

```
for cell in ws.columns[0]:
    if cell.value=='setoff':
        for i in range(0,2):
           cell.value = '{}_{}'.format(cell.value, i)
wb.save('OP_1.xlsx')
```

My code doesn't distinct the duplicates instead appends as duplicates.

Please guide.

Actual Spreadsheet values:

[image: Actual Spreadsheet values] 
Expected Updates/Modification:

[image: Expected Modifications]

Answer (score 0):

Your code needs to count how often a cell value has already been seen in order append the correct suffix. Here is a solution making use of Python's built-in [`Counter`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter) class:

```
from collections import Counter

c = Counter()
for cell in ws.columns[0]:
    if c[cell.value]>0:
        cell.value = '{}_{}'.format(cell.value, c[cell.value])
    c[cell.value]+=1
wb.save('OP_1.xlsx')
```

Comment: Thanks Corinna!! it works but third set doesn't get updated. i mean 2nd and 3rd set getting updated as same with suffix '_1'. Expectation is 3rd set supposed to be updated with '_2'.

Comment: Also i m trying to get cell values based on the headers highlighted in yellow. for e.g. "if cell.value = m_terms, if print (setoff) - result supposed to be corresponding cell value 'Y'. how do we achieve this?

Comment: I think there's no error in my code. Are you sure that you have written ```c[cell.value]+=1``` instead of ```c[cell.value]=1```? Your attempt of getting cell values based on highlighted headers is beyond the scope of your original question, maybe you should open an new one.

Comment: Yes. No error thrown but doesn't get update the 3rd set. Anyway Thanks for your inputs.